# Property 'component' does not exist reactjs + materialUI + typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, material-ui

I am creating custom typography. But while using I am getting below error.

I am following below document

https://mui.com/material-ui/api/typography/

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-mountain-eukirg

```
import * as React from "react";
import Typography, { TypographyProps } from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const LabelXs = styled(Typography)<TypographyProps>(({ fontWeight }) => {
  return {
    fontSize: 15
  };
});

export default LabelXs;
```

I am using like this

```
 <LabelXs component={"div"}>Div element</LabelXs>
```

don't why it is showing error ?

[image]

```
  [![Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SystemProps<Theme> & { align?: "right" | "left" | "inherit" | "center" | "justify" | undefined; children?: ReactNode; ... 6 more ...; variantMapping?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...> & MUIStyledCommonProps<...>'.ts(2322)][1]][1]
```

any suggestion ?

[image]
component props is present why you are saying it is not present
https://mui.com/material-ui/api/typography/

Comment: If you go to `Typography.d.ts` file you will see that there is no `component` prop. I do not why. You could edit that file if it makes any sense.

Comment: Have you tried the options in the MUI docs? https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/composition/#with-typescript

Answer (score 2):

Component seems not to be present in TypographyProps. Therefore, inspired by @SteveGomez, you can do something like: `<TypographyProps & {component: React.ElementType}>`

```
import * as React from "react";
import Typography, { TypographyProps } from "@mui/material/Typography";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const LabelXs = styled(Typography)<TypographyProps & {component: React.ElementType}>(({ fontWeight }) => {
  return {
    fontSize: 15
  };
});

export default LabelXs;
```

EDIT:
You could also use `{component: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements}`.

Comment:  You don't need `component: string` -- `React.ElementType` should be sufficient. Or even: `component: keyof JSX.IntrinsicElements`

Comment: @SteveGomez thanks for answering , But I saw there is `component` props in documentation . see my updated question

Comment: @SteveGomez https://mui.com/material-ui/api/typography/

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use the component prop, the type of the props should be used with type arguments. Just use React.ElementType as mentioned in the docs.

```
const LabelXs = styled(Typography)<
  TypographyProps & { component: React.ElementType }
>(({ fontWeight }) => {
  return {
    fontSize: 15
  };
});
```

Now `component` accepts any React Custom Component and HTML element.

[Docs](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-lalande-c6l1xd?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: But I saw there is component props in documentation . see my updated question –